# WebView does not show KOLIBRI log in page

Tags: android, android-studio, http, webview

Hi I'm new in Android Studio. I'm developing an app that uses the WebView to open a http url. This http url is used to access learning materials in my school that I'm working. The webview is working properly in other websites and also it can access my routers settings. I can't make it work in http://192.168.100.73:8080. The webview only displays the icon but it works when I remove the line  myWebView.setWebViewClient((new WebViewClient())); which I don't want to do. I can't search similar problem in google.

My manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.gves.studentresources">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StudentResources"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.StudentResources.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

the fragment layout

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview1"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="729dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

the fragment java class

```
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();


    WebView myWebView = root.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //myWebView.setWebViewClient((new WebViewClient()));
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.100.73:8080");

    return root;
}
```

Screenshot while the app is running. The webview shows the icon but nothing happens.
[with new webview code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRITb.png)

Screenshot when I remove the myWebView.setWebViewClient((new WebViewClient())); line code
[without new webview code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7eQk.png)

I'm using Android Studio's default navigation drawer template. I hope you could help me with this.

Comment: Please post clickable links.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by adding this line.

myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

but I have another problem. The download resource button in Webview is missing. [google chrome in bluestaks compared to android studio emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRtSk.png)